# Where does BIOS store boot sequence?

Tags: bios, uefi

Every time I format and re-install a different OS, a new boot option appears in the BIOS settings. Where is this stored? Can I read or modify it from within the OS?

Comment: I added a UEFI tag as this is not actually BIOS related, but UEFI, which is a different beast than classic BIOS. Classic BIOS has no idea about OS. It just tries to boot from the first device that appears to be bootable. I'm not familiar enough with the intricacies of UEFI to write a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computer lists individual operating systems in its "BIOS" settings, means it runs UEFI firmware (as do most PCs from the last decade or so) and not a traditional BIOS. (Actual BIOS-based computers in the past did not have such boot options – they only cared about actual disks, and the "choose an OS" boot menu had to be provided *by* the OS itself.)

One of the changes in UEFI is that it brings its own OS selection menu, storing the OS entries within the motherboard (where all other firmware settings are stored) in the form of "EFI variables" – not on the disk.

Any OS can access the EFI variables and boot entries, though not all of them actually come with tools for that. (Also, only those running on native UEFI, not when the "BIOS emulation" is active.)

- From within Linux, the UEFI boot entries can be accessed through efibootmgr. Start with `efibootmgr -v` to list all entries, then `--delete` the useless entries by their ID.
- From within Windows, the UEFI boot entries can be accessed through `bcdedit`, intermixed with Windows' own BOOTMGR boot entries. Start with `bcdedit /enum firmware` to list all UEFI boot entries, then `/delete` the unwanted ones by their ID.

  (If by chance you *weren't* talking about the firmware boot menu, but about the Windows' own boot menu, bcdedit can deal with both in the same way.)
- FreeBSD also has efibootmgr, but the options are slightly different. NetBSD, OpenBSD currently don't include such tools yet.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, I have a slight alteration of Tonny's  rather vague comment on your question: the Basic Input/Output System, per se, doesn't decide what drive to boot up from, but what you configured in the boot sequence settings of the BIOS. I'm not sure how the successor of this tool, the UEFI relates to this, but if what you mean with "a new boot option appears" is [this](https://ibb.co/zxHSx6t), then, yes. You can, in fact, manipulate this somewhat annoying dialogue whenever you boot your system within the Windows operating system. [Here's a step-by-step tutorial on how you can disable this feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PM8x_p5lFg).

Additional information:
The BIOS software is stored in the Electrically Erasable and Programmable Read-only Memory (EEPROM). Older versions involved the UV-EPROM, where, as the name suggests, the memory is deleted via ultraviolet radiation before it could be reprogrammed. On the other hand, this pop-up menu (distinct from dialogue boxes; more info. [here](http://quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-dialogue-box-and-a-pop-up-menu)) prompting you to choose an OS to boot from among all of the drives you have installed that contain OSes is formatted with the style of the operating system currently being ran by the system. Hence, it is stored within that OS. (That isn't the most rational reason for it, but I reckon it sufficed.) Feel free to correct any quirks that I may have made. Have a great day!